# Meaning of "tricoinium"?

Tags: meaning

In **Rome:Its people life and customs** by Ugo Enrico Paoli, some rooms in plans of Pompeiian houses are marked *tricoinium* with no explanation or definition. I cannot find this, either in my own dictionary nor L&S or other online dictionaries. Is this a mispelling/mistranslation - the book was originally written in Italian?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presumably a typo for [triclinium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triclinium).

Comment: Yes, I suspected that. On various plans the rooms are designated dining rooms (5 of them - the Romans did like their food!) .